# How to use the Member Function of a class in form1.aspx

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have created new website and a class viz Form1.aspx and class1.cs. I have also created some function in that class. Now i wants to use that function in form1.aspx. can any one tell me How i can use that?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you intend to do, but usually when you create a page like `Form1.aspx`, it creates a behind code file like `Form1.aspx.cs`.

In the `Form1.aspx.cs` file you have events that go through the page cycle like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
}
```

where you can add anything (any functionality) you want to do when the Form1.aspx loads.

Now if you created a separate class , say `class1.cs` and you have some functionality in that class that you can use on your `Form1.aspx` page, you would add some code in any of the provided functions by the .net framework like "Page_Load", or you can create your own in that file. Lets say you will be using the page load then you will do something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    class1 myClass = new class1();
    //if your function in myClass returns some kind of type (i.e string, int, or if   its just void then you need to account for that
    myClass.CallAnyFunctionInClass1(send any parameters here);
}
```

**My advice:** Read about objected oriented programming http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/csharpclasses.htm Object oriented programming tutorial

Comment: That is not allowing to create object. am i need to add anything for including that class... Like that.

Comment: Its very hard to say because I am not sure how you have set your project. Maybe you should screenshot the solution explorer to see how and where you have placed these